# How to refer to strings in an external class (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How would it be possible to reference an external string in an external class.

e.g.

Class1.cs:

```
MessageBox.Show(mystring);
```

Class2.cs:

```
public static void myMethod()
{
string mystring = "foobar";

// some logic here
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve? Usually it can be accomplished without doing something like this

Comment: You don't. Variables that are declared in a method have a scope limited to that method, so what you're asking for is a technical impossibility. -- You might want to add a `public static string` to the class in order to access it from outside the class.

Comment: @skaz I am trying to check a boolean value in a method in class2. E.g. if the method run in class2 changes the boolean value in that method, the method in class1 can check this and do some logic

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvotes on a question like this. Obviously this can't be accomplished (at least not how the question is posted) due to variable scope. But, instead of downvoting the question (as James may be learning), why not answer the question that way and then offer an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If I right understood your question, you can do something like this:

```
public class2 
{
    public static string MyString 
    {
       get {return "foobar"; }
    }

}


public class1 
{
    public void DoSomething() 
    {
       MessageBox.Show(class2.MyString );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
public static class Foo
{
    public const string FOO_CONST = "value";
}

public class Bar
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.FOO_CONST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new instance of Class2 you can make MyString public or pull it out into a get method:

```
//In Class1
Class2 class2 = new Class2();
MessageBox.Show(class2.Mystring());

//In Class2
public string Mystring{ get; set; }
```

Or you could return the string from the method

```
public static string myMethod()
{
    string myString = "foobar";
    //logic goes here
    return myString;
}

//In Class1
Class2 class2 = new Class2();
MessageBox.Show(class2.MyMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification to your question:

> I am trying to check a boolean value in a method in class2. E.g. if
>   the method run in class2 changes the boolean value in that method, the
>   method in class1 can check this and do some logic

You could do something like this:

```
class Class1 {

  Class2 myClass = new Class2();

  public void ActivityMethod() {
    myClass.MethodThatMayChangeBoolean();
    if(myClass.myBoolean) {
      // Response to a truth change.
    } else {
      // Respond to a false change.
    }
  }
}

class Class2 {
  public boolean myBoolean { get; }

  public void MethodThatMayChangeBoolean() {
    // Do stuff in here that may change boolean.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Properties

```
 private static string _mystring = "foobar";
 public static string mystring 
 {
    get { return _mystring ; }
    set { _mystring = value; }
 }
```

Or use auto properties and initialize their values in the static constructor of the class:

```
 public static string mystring { get; set; }

 public static MyStaticClass()
 {
   mystring = "foobar";
 }
```